# Objective C, crash when dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

my apps is crashing when i dismiss from modal view. Here is my code

BaseViewController -

```
- (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)menuContainerViewController {
        return (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.navigationController.parentViewController;
}

-(void) setup 
{    

    BaseViewController *baseViewController = [[BaseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BaseViewController" bundle:nil]; 
        UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
        NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:baseViewController];
        navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
}

- (void)call 
{
    PopUpViewController *popUpViewController = [[PopUpViewController alloc] init];
    [popUpViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self presentViewController:popUpViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

PopUpViewController -

```
-(void) close {
    if([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else 
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(close)
                               withObject:nil
                            waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

When execute "setup" > "call" function, it's switch to PopUpViewController. When i try to trigger "close" function from PopUpViewController and it crash. It only happen on IOS7 other than that is just fine.

i got this error message from Zombie Object

```
-[BaseViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15e8e050
```

**UPDATE ******
I had changed my mind, instead of create a new instance for navigationController, i just setup a new View for baseViewController and it won't crash anymore.

Comment: Can you in setup method, after you created baseViewController do if (!baseViewController) NSLog(@"baseViewController is nil"); It will make sure that your controller is not nil.

Comment: Hi, baseViewController is not nil and after do some code tracing, the apps is crashing after BaseViewController "viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated" event.

Comment: You can't call the method close from popupviewcontroller if close doesn't defined in popupviewcontroller. You should declare a delegate in your popupviewcontroller and set the delegate as the viewcontroller from where you want to present popupviewcontroller. Then you can call close through delegate..

Comment: Enable `NSZombies` and you'll hopefully be able to find where your code is crashing.

Comment: Already he has enabled

Comment: to @jailani habeeb, i'm wonder why it didn't crash when i skip the "setup" method and directly "call" the PopUpViewController. It just work nicely... /.\"

Comment: is your baseviewcontroller in index 0 of navigationcontroller?

Comment: to @jailani habeeb > yup...

Comment: Ok...How do dismiss your popupviewcontroller? Do you have any cancel button in popupviewcontroller?

Comment: yes, i do have a "back" button on the popupviewcontroller to execute the "close" method

Comment: is that possible of because i setup a new baseViewController inside the BaseViewController and the "old" baseViewController instance is still exist behind the scene, so the popupviewcontroller don't know where to return?

Comment: where did you define the action for close button? popVC, BaseVC or appDelegate?

Comment: I defined it at popVC, there's no delegate between popVC/BaseVC. Btw I had change another way to solved it, see my new update**. Thanks all.